# How to extract the minimum or maximum last recent row from the table using mysql?

Tags: mysql

---

My Mysql database:

```
| time       | Name     | TYU
| 1483347398 | vprasad  | PDSP_DES                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
| 1483348583 | akawle   | LPT
```

**My Query:

I had used the (select * from users) query to retrieve the above table.Now i need to output the entire row from  the database according to the minimum or maximum time from the table name.

So far i tried:

i had tried the following query (select min(time) from users).i dont to know how to retrieve the entire row using min(time) or max(time) using mysql.

**My output:**

```
min(time)  |
+------------+
| 1482484399 |
+------------+
```

**My expected output:**

```
 | 1483348583 | akawle   | LPT
```

Comment: select time, Name, TYU from users where time = min(time)

Comment: It shows error asInvalid use of group funciton@manny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sorting method.

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY time ASC LIMIT 1
```

1. sort by ASC to get smallest as first result
2. limit 1 so you get only 1 result (the smallest)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
SELECT time, name, TYU FROM users WHERE time = (select min(time) from users)
```

Answer (score 0):

as your output try this:-

for **max()** time

```
select time,Name,TYU from tt where time = (select max(time) from tt);
```

for **min()** time

```
select time,Name,TYU from tt where time = (select min(time) from tt);
```

check on fiddle:-[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/abd6c3/10)

Answer (score -1):

you should try this:

*SELECT min(time) as min_time,name,TYU FROM users.*

it would result like :
1483347398 |  vprasad  |  PDSP_DES

because in (1483348583 and 1483347398), 1483347398 is minimum.

OR

if you want result like: 
1483348583  akawle  LPT

you should try this:
*SELECT max(time) as min_time,name,TYU FROM users.*

OR

if you want all rows then you can try like this:

*SELECT time,name,TYU FROM users order by time asc.*